Время по умолчанию в поле mysql
Из php в запросе на запись, передаю значение time() времени...
Что за тип для поля необходимо использовать, в которое заносим содержимое time()/php?
Возможно ли по умолчанию для поля, при добавлении строки, чтобы по умолчанию прописывалось временная метка, время добавления записи?

The TIME Type Хотя время без даты - это немного странновато..

Используйте настройку в создании таблице с установкой дефолтного параметра
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Автоматически записывает время, но записывает его в формате и при выборе отдает в формате. Возможно ли записать в том же формате, что отдает time()/php. Просто числом

Так time() в php выдаёт timestamp, насколько я понимаю, это просто int. Может в int записывать, но зависит от того, что вы с этим дальше делать собираетесь.

В том и дело, рассчитываю убрать запись времени из php. Сразу по умолчанию сделать, чтобы при записи строки, выставлялось время в int, не в формате, просто числом.

По сути time в php выдаёт timestamp в виде int значения. В MySql так не получится сделать, там timestamp - это дата и время. Но можно при желании преобразовать их в int.
Создание двух полей таблицы типа timestamp, в одно поле будет записано время создания записи в таблице, а в другое время обновления таблицы. Подсмотрено здесь.
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ts1 TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ,ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);

Преобразование в INT значение (отсюда):
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts1) from t1;

Но нужно иметь в виду, что возможны разные приколы с time zone, переводом на летнее/зимнее время и т.д.
По идее, можно и сразу INT поле в таблице сделать, если использовать в качестве значения UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()).
